# Select and Update hibernate caching table

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, orm, ehcache

I'm just implementing the hibernate query cache. I just want to know the behavior/working of hibernate cache concept if I do a manual update and hibernate update on the table which has been cached already.

Scenario:

1. Select cache Table A
2. Update Table A (manually or hibernate)
3. Select Table A again

The changes are reflected or I need to restart the server.

Below are my hibernate properties

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <value>
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
        hibernate.format_sql=true
        hibernate.show_sql=false
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
        hibernate.generate_statistics=true
        org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/ehcache.xml
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    </value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always update the `TableA` through Hibernate API, then the [Query Cache](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-query-cache-work/) might get invalidated.

1. With HQL, you are safe because Hibernate can extract the updated tables and invalidate the query cache regions that might get stale.
2. With native queries, all Query Cache regions are invalidated whenever you run a native SML statement. To restrict the affected Query Cache regions, you need to specify a `Synchronization` as follow:

   ```
   session.createSQLQuery(
       "update TableA set name = '\"'||name||'\"' "
   )
   .addSynchronizedEntityClass(TableA.class)
   .executeUpdate()
   ```